# xdebug for php 7 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xdebug, php-7, phpize

I'm trying to get xdebug working on PHP 7. I'm build the xdebug.so file from version http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.4.0rc4.tgz. The phpize output looks correct (`Zend Extension Api No:  320151012`) however I get `Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220121212.` from PHP.

So I've followed these instructions:

> Tailored Installation Instructions
>
> Summary
>
> Xdebug installed: no Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler Windows: no Zend
>   Server: no PHP Version: 7.0.9-1 Zend API nr: 320151012 PHP API nr:
>   20151012 Debug Build: no Thread Safe Build: no Configuration File
>   Path: /etc/php/7.0/apache2 Configuration File:
>   /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini Extensions directory:
>   /usr/lib/php/20151012 Instructions
>
> Download xdebug-2.4.1.tgz Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf
>   xdebug-2.4.1.tgz Run: cd xdebug-2.4.1 Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you
>   don't have phpize.
>
> As part of its output it should show:
>
> Configuring for: ... Zend Module Api No:      20151012 Zend Extension
>   Api No:   320151012 If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize.
>   Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.
>
> Run: ./configure Run: make Run: cp modules/xdebug.so
>   /usr/lib/php/20151012 Edit /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini and add the
>   line zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so Restart the
>   webserver

With the exception that I've installed php7.0-dev instead of php5 `apt-get install -y php7.0-dev`.

When I run the `phpize` command I get the following output:

> Configuring for:
>
> PHP Api Version:         20151012
>
> Zend Module Api No:      20151012
>
> Zend Extension Api No:  320151012

As expected. However when I run PHP I get:

> Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220121212.
>
> The Zend Engine API version 320151012 which is installed, is newer.
>
> Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later
>   version of Xdebug.

I'm obviously doing something wrong somewhere! Any help on debugging the issue is very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I fixed this by using the apt-get package:
`apt-get install -y php-xdebug`

This seems to install the correct xdebug.so file and everything is working!

Comment: I had `Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 320151012. The Zend Engine API version 320170718 which is installed, is newer.` error and your solution worked for me. (only had missing `xdebug.so` error so I just copied file where it was missing, in my case `/usr/lib/php/20151012`)

Comment: This worked for me twoo with the `Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version XXXXXXXXX` error. I had to remove `xdebug.so` attemps from the php.ini so the `apt-get` can add it durint installation